# USB HID programming

Tags: usb, hid, msr

I need some help getting started with programming a USB HID magnetic stripe reader device (MSR605X) in C#. I have some experience with an older model of this device which uses standard USB COM ports and I was able to access it via the SerialPort class in .NET
Any help on how to send read and write commands would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You tried to use the SerialPort class again?

Comment: Yes, but you'd need a COM port for that. Apparently HID devices don't get any COM ports assigned to them.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126958/windows-service-in-c-sharp-and-detect-hid-usb-card-reader-issue) SO question.